# Extensible list of lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a GUI application which lets user to create sections and subsections for a specific section. The user can add new sections and add new subsections to a section any time. Finally I have a list viewer which will display the whole things every time I click a 'Refresh' button.

For the section part, I have created a List of string:

```
public static ArrayList<String> sections = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For the subsection part I want to create a List of List which will create a List of all the sections. I have used something like this, but the problem is I cannot uniquely identify each List using a section name:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> subsections = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I want a data structure which will let me create a list based on a section name and will also let me add string in it any time. Any help?

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for that it is a collection of key,value pair.

```
public static Map<String,List<String>> subsections = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **HashMap**

```
Map<String, List<String>> section = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```